# SharePoint: How to prevent doc lib field from being synchronized with Office documents?

Tags: 2013, metadata, office

I have a SharePoint document library used to store Office documents (pptx, docx, ...). This library uses a custom content type for documents and this content type contains a field that serves internal purposes, let's call it *Promoted*.

Now when creating and editing Office documents in the library this *Promoted* field is available for editing in Word, PowerPoint, etc. in the **Properties** view of the document like this:

[image: SharePoint field that should not be available for editing]

The user can change the value and when saving or uploading the document to SharePoint the value is preserved and synced to the SharePoint field. That has to stop.

**How can I prevent this field from being synchronized between SharePoint and Office applications?**

I don't want any synchronization at all. The field belongs to SharePoint. And should stay there. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

The field does still belong to SharePoint but the Office documents show custom SharePoint properties in that window, that's built in behavior.

Have you tried making the field read-only and seeing if that stops the ability to change it from Office apps?

Comment: Unfortunately, that wouldn't solve my problem as I also need to prevent the value from travelling with the document. When the user downloads the document and uploads it again (in another doclib) the value mustn't be there.